# Elements still bouncing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

*update* - Added a video

I've made things like you can see in many tutorials and forums:

- created Physic Material I called "`No bounce`"
- set `Dynamic Friction = 0` and `Static Friction = 0`
- created a cube and add a `Box collider` with `Material = "No Bounce"`
- set `Mass = 1`, `Drag = 0` and `Angular Drag = 0`

Now I add another cube for the ground, made it very large and added a `Box collider` with `Material = "No Bounce"`

I have 2 problems:
- when they collide, the cube bounces (whereas it shouldn't with my configuration)
- I've made a script and attached it to the cube, to change the velocity, and set it to `0` when there's a collision:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CubeProperties : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody _rb;
    private bool _landing;

    private void Start()
    {
        _rb = GetComponentInParent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        Debug.Log("Collision");
        _landing = true;
    }

    public void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (!_landing) {
            return;
        }
        _rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        _landing = false;
    }    
}
```

So at the first collision, I try to instant stop the cube with `_rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;`. But *changing velocity has no effect*, I dont understand why. I've tried with many value to see what happens... but nothing happened.
The only thing I can add, and it's working, is: `AddForce()` I tried to a negative value, but this doesn't work either.

What did I forgot?

Here's a video I hope this is easy to understand (and I hope I'm allowed to help with a video):

https://youtu.be/I3C1KBmm5yw

Comment: I don't know Unity well, but from a purely physics point of view friction=0 would mean something slippy like ice and have nothing to do with whether things bounce off it or not. I'd expect the bounciness constant to be called "coefficient of restitution" or similar.

Comment: Unity doesnt use physics naming properly, for exemple you could search how they use the word "`Mass`" to make physic-based calculations...

Comment: Looking at your setup in the video (and knowing some quirks of unity's systems). Can you change it from OnCollisionEnter to OnCollisionStay just to try it? If that works I have another idea.

Comment: That's very kind of you I'll try this later, but for now I have brought "back" my old code which was moving "by hand" the cubes, and solved my small algorithm problem. The cubes fall with my code = no gravity and no collision detection: I stop them by code. This works like a charm now, after solving optimization problem (to paraphrase Unity: C# invented garbage collector to make your life easier and have less code, but in the end it's often bad and you end up doing ugly code that avoid GC to work! And the final code is much *uglier* than with clean allocation/free code)

Comment: My other problem and is probably linked with my question is that I dont have "one unit = one meter". On the contrary! I did a 900x1600 resolution, which, in Unity, gives 900 meters x 1600 meters. And thus my sphere is 100 meters tall! So, of course, there's a unit problem, and moving a 100m object is **slow**, and the object falls slowly. Everything is realistic, so my #1 job will be to scale everything down to the correct "one unit = one meter".

Comment: And that's why, on the Unity side, *maybe*, a huge mass object might rebound even though you said "no rebound". The other last thing is about pure 3D: imagine in frame #1 the object is *before* the plane, and in #2 it's *after*: it has to bring the object "back" thus applies a bit of negative force. This is a wild guess. So, maybe Unity has a callback that can be called *just before the collision happens*. Maybe. I don't know I'm a total beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your mixing 2D physics and 3D physics together. If it's a 2D scene, you'll actually want to use the [2D Rigidbody](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.html) and [Box Collider 2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-BoxCollider2D.html).

If it's a 3D Scene which is what it seems like, then you just want to make sure you're using the normal [OnCollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html). As it stands, the OnCollisionEnter2D won't get called in that setup.

Just to help see if things are getting called, a good tip in Unity is the [Debug.Log](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html). It'll send a message to the console if it gets fired off.

Comment: this is the correct answer. also if you want the object to stop immediatly on contact, you ca set the rigidbody to kinematic. but only if you want it to stay there for good.

Comment: This doesnt work. I forgot to say that I tried in both 2D and now I tried the solution in 3D, but I posted this question between my 2D and 3D attempts, sorry for that. I've updated my question to reflect the reality. This drives me nuts: 1 hour to make the whole stuff working, 2 days lost trying in every possible way without any working solution.

Comment: In 2D it worked better, because AddForce2D did work. Here nothing is working, it's like if I were working on the bad RigidBody, whereas OnCollisionEnter() is properly called.

Comment: WTF it seems it's a scale problem. I did a "rounded" cube on blender, exported it and it was very very small, I had to change the scale to 49.1 Everything was working, including collision detection but even setting "rigidbody to kinematic" didn't work. If I try with them with a scale of 1, setting "rigidbody to kinematic" works. I'll investigate further.

Comment: I was wrong nothing changes I've recorded a video and updated the question.

Comment: I've checked your answer as valid even though the support itself (I was paying for the support!!) didn't help *at all*.